# Rails RR Framework: multiple calls for instance_of

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, bdd

I would like write RSpec for my controller using RR.

I wrote following code:

```
require File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/../spec_helper')

describe RegistrationController do

    it "should work" do 
        #deploy and approve are member functions
        stub.instance_of(Registration).approve { true }
        stub.instance_of(Registration).deploy { true }
        post :register
    end 
end
```

However RR stubs only **deploy** method when still calls original **approve** method.

What syntax should I use to stub both method calls for all instances of Registration class?

**UPDATE:**
I achivied desired result with [Mocha]

```
Registration.any_instance.stubs(:deploy).returns(true)
Registration.any_instance.stubs(:approve).returns(true)
```

Answer (score 1):

It would appear the behavior you describe is actually a bug:

http://github.com/btakita/rr/issues#issue/17

Answer (score -1):

as far as I know, the RSpec mocks don't allow you to do that. Are you sure, that you need to stub all instances? I usually follow this pattern:

```
describe RegistrationController do
    before(:each) do
       @registration = mock_model(Registration, :approve => true, :deploy => true)
       Registration.stub!(:find => @registration)
       # now each call to Registration.find will return my mocked object
    end

    it "should work" do 
      post :register
      reponse.should be_success
    end

    it "should call approve" do
      @registration.should_receive(:approve).once.and_return(true)
      post :register
    end

    # etc 
end
```

By stubbing the find method of the Registration class you control, what object gets returned in the spec.

Comment: The question is about RR stubs, not RSpec stubs.